# Showing Different Navbar to Signed In Users in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm using React with Firebase. I want to show different navbars to users depending on whether they are signed in or not however, I'm not 100% sure on how to go about it. Here is what I'm starting with. I'd create two components and render the other Nav. Highly doubt this approach is right.

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
  toggleNav: function(){
    // some code 
  }
  render: function() {
    return (
     <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
       <div className="container-fluid">
         <div className="navbar-header">
           <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
         </div>
         <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
           <li onClick={this.createQuiz}><a href="#">Create Quiz</a></li>
           <li onClick={this.toggleNav}><a href="#">Sign In/ Sign Up</a></li> 
         </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>
    )
   }
 });

 ReactDOM.render(<Nav />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Or should I be doing something like this instead? I'd create the UserNav component below obviously.

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">
      {user ? <UserNav /> : <Nav />}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could either create two components, each of which represents one specific navbar or you could create just one navbar component and pass the respective elements of your navbar as props or preferably children like this:

```
function NavBar(props) {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        // Loop over {props.children}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

function NavBar-Link(props) {
  return (
    <li>
      Your link. You probably want to pass some props like 'text', 'link', ... to it
    </li>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar>
    <NavBar-Link />
    <NavBar-Link />
    <NavBar-Link />
    // ...
  </NavBar>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

You have the user's login state stored somewhere. Either locally in your component or in any flux-like framework like redux, it doesn't matter. In your component that imports your NavBar component the login state would determine which set of NavBar-Link Components you'd want to pass just like in your latter example. I hope you get the general idea :)

EDIT:
Additionally, each component that should only be accessible by a certain role should also check the login state and render either itself/nothing/a 403 warning/... respectively to avoid someone accessing it manually.